# How to determine the number of feature maps to use in a convolutional neural network layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I've been doing a lot of reading on Conv Nets and even some playing using Julia's Mocha.jl package (which looks a lot like Caffe, but you can play with it in the Julia REPL).

In a Conv net, Convolution layers are followed by "feature map" layers. What I'm wondering is how does one determine how many feature maps a network needs to have to solve some particular problem? Is there any science to this or is it more art? I can see that if you're trying to make a classification at least that last layer should have number of feature maps == number of classes (unless you've got a fully connected MLP at the top of the network, I suppose).

In my case, I 'm not doing a classification so much as trying to come up with a value for every pixel in an image (I suppose this could be seen as a classification where the classes are from 0 to 255).

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, I'm trying to solve a regression problem where the outputs are in a range from 0 to 255 (grayscale in this case). Still, the question remains: How does one determine how many feature maps to use at any given convolution layer? Does this differ for a regression problem vs. a classification problem?

Comment: Classification assumes that it's equally bad to predict 0 instead of 255 as 254 instead of 255. Most likely, it's not the case for you, so you might want to solve a regression problem instead of classification one.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe: yes. Still, the vast majority of papers I see on CNNs are solving a classification problem, not a regression problem. In either case I'm wondering how the number of feature maps to use is determined.

Comment: @BartoszKP, your statement does not make any sense unless you specify loss function. The two most popular (from my point of view) are cross-entropy (classification) and L2-loss (regression). And cross-entropy doesn't depend on concrete numerical values of targets, neither it depends on their order.

Comment: @BartoszKP, but L2-loss is used for regression, not classification. Of course, you can try to solve classification as regression, but it's simply wrong from theoretical and intuitive sides.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe Seems it's too late for me to think straight :) I'll remove my comments, thanks for the discussion, you're right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, like any other hyperparameter - by evaluting results on separate development set and finding what number works best. It also worth checking publications that deal with similar problem and finding what number of feature maps they were using.

Comment: There is a trend that the number of filters increase as you go deeper into the layers of the conv net. Is there any reason to do this?

Comment: I am no expert on cnn, but I would guess this is due to the combinatorics character of features composition.

Answer (score 1):

More art. The only difference between imagenet winners that use conv-nets has been changing the structure of layers and maybe some novel ways of training.

VGG is a neat example. Begins with filter sizes beginning with 2^7, then 2^8, then 2^9 followed by fully connected layers, then an output layer which will give you your classes. Your maps and layer depths can be completely unrelated to the number of output classes.

You would not want a fully connected layer at the top. That kind of defeats the purpose that convolutional nets were designed to solve (overfitting and optimizing hundreds of thousands of weights per neuron)

Training on big sets will require some heavy computational resources. If you're working with imagenet - there's a set of pre-trained models with caffe that you could build on top of http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/model_zoo.html

I'm not sure if you can port these to mocha. There's a port to tensor flow though if you're interested in that https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow